# Multiple Bluetooth speakers simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to pair two sticky dude Bluetooth speakers, at one time with my iPhone. With two of them at once it would be like stereo sound. Is there an app or something maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the same Bluetooth device profile with more than one deivce at the same time.  You won't be able to do what you want to do.

For a listing of all the different profiles, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) entry.

*But I can have multiple Bluetooth devices paired to my iPhone.  I have a keyobard, a headset and speakers.*

Each uses a different profile.  Your keyboard is considered an HID (Human Inteface Device) while your headset uses the HSP profile and your audio (speakers) likely uses the A2DP profile.

These profiles are 1-1.  Meaning one profile to one device at a time.

If you want stereo get a [stereo receiver](http://amzn.to/1LWhd5Y) that supports Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The new iOS (and iPadOS) audio-sharing feature uses Bluetooth to split audio between two different devices. Specific requirements change depending on which sharing method you use (more on that in a bit), but both users will need a pair of AirPods or Powerbeats Pro wireless earphones, as well as one of the following devices (running iOS or iPadOS 13):

- iOS 13: iPhone 8, 8 Plus, X, XR, XS, or XS Mini; or an iPod Touch (seventh-generation).
- iPadOS 13: iPad Pro 11-inch; iPad Pro 12.9-inch (second-generation or later); iPad Air (third-generation); iPad mini (fifth-generation).

The final iOS/iPadOS 13 release will also allow users to share audio by syncing up two sets of Bluetooth headphones to a single handset.

- Put both pairs of Bluetooth headphones into pairing mode (this varies by model—check your user manual or do a quick internet search if you don’t know how to do this).
- On the iOS/iPadOS 13 device you wish to use for playback, go to Settings > Bluetooth
- Tap the names of each unpaired device to connect both headphones.
- Both headphones will now play the same audio simultaneously, but volume and playback can only be controlled on the iPhone/iPad.